# how to resolve COALESCE result in doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I currently have a query of the form:

```
SELECT
  ...
  COALESCE(a1_.date_field, a2_.date_field) AS sclr_x
FROM a1_
JOIN a2_
...
```

By default, the [doctrine coalesce expression](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.17.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/AST/CoalesceExpression.php) resolves to a string. To handle this I run the query result through an array_map as

```
return array_map(convertStringToDate, $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

I would prefer to avoid iterating all of the result sets to resolve the coalesce field.

Is there a way to tell the coalesce expression to resolve to a specific type? If not, what is the correct way to create a custom expression/function/resolve/etc to handle this?